# I'm trying to extract the values of an object using destructuring assignment, the age variable says undefined. What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, object, dom, ecmascript-6

```js
const obj = {
  firstUser: {
    name: {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
    },
    age: 32,
  }
}

const {
  firstUser: {
    name: {
      lastName: Lname
    }
  },
  age
} = obj;

console.log(Lname);
console.log(age);
```

Comment: `age` is a property of `firstUser`, not `obj`: `{firstUser:{name: {lastName: Lname}, age}}`

Comment: Oh I see, that was really silly of me. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth formatting your code (like I did in the snippet) so you can see the structure of the objects more easily @UddeshTidke.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
const { firstUser } = obj;
const { name, age } = firstUser;
const { lastName: Lname } = name; // this is destructuring assignment
```

Now you can use lastName as Lname variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have placed the age field inside firstName object,nested inside the obj. I have refactored your code

```js
 const obj = {
  firstUser: {
    name: {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
    },
  },
  age: 32,
}


const {firstUser:{name: {lastName: Lname}}, age} = obj;

console.log(Lname);
console.log(age);
```